# Can't load FXML in another package (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

For some reason I'm getting an error when I try to load an FXML which is in a different package:

**MainApp.java**"

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            System.out.println("view folder: " + MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));     // returns null
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

Error message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
        at checkmydigitalfootprint.MainApp.initRootLayout(MainApp.java:73)
        at checkmydigitalfootprint.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:55)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
Exception running application checkmydigitalfootprint.MainApp
```

Comment: This seems to be eclipse, right? Had a similar issue and using the full resource path helped: `MainApp.class.getResource("/checkmydigitalfootprint/view/RootLayout.fxml")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you what works for me. Firstly, the FXML files should be considered resources rather than Java source files, so they're best placed into their own directory tree. Your source code is currently living in the `/src/main/java` tree, so your FXML files should be moved into the `/src/main/resources` tree, ideally into a subdirectory called `fxml`. (I also have a subdirectory called `i18n` which holds the resource bundles to define text labels in multiple languages.)

Once your FXML files are found under the path `/src/main/resources/fxml` you should be able to load them from your JavaFX controllers with something like this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
URL fxmlLocation = getClass().getResource("/fxml/main_screen.fxml");
loader.setLocation(fxmlLocation);
loader.setController(mainScreenController);
loader.setResources(ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n/Text", new Locale("sv", "SE")));
Pane pane = loader.<Pane>load();
Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
```

(If the root element of your FXML file does not represent a `Pane` then you'll need to modify the line which calls the `load()` method, and replace `Pane` with the appropriate type.)

Note that the call to `getResource(String)` takes a path which begins with a forward-slash, and that represents the resource path root `/src/main/resources/`.

And also note that, bizarrely, the call to `getBundle(String)` does *not* start with a forward-slash, even though you're targeting exactly the same `/src/main/resources/` path. I have to admit I can't explain why these two methods need to be treated slightly differently like this, but this code works to load both the "main_screen.fxml" file and the Swedish language resource bundle file "Text_sv_SE.properties".

Comment: Thanks ! I moved it to src/main/resources and called "RootLayout.xml" and worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try for anyone experiencing this is to make sure that your fxml file is not empty. Open it in scenebuilder and drag an Anchor pane. That is what worked for me