# why does fxml loader stop working for no reason

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I wrote the following code and it worked. After i changed the fxml file to the resources folder it stopped working. I put it back at the original place and it won't work. WHY? I've this problem for months.

```
package com.opensoftware.helptec.ui;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HomepageApplication extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("src/main/resources/fxml/homepage.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

FXML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" fx:controller="com.opensoftware.helptec.ui.HomeUiController">
    <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="268.0" layoutY="300.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onClick"
            text="Click Me!"/>
    <Label layoutX="274.0" layoutY="116.0" text="Welcome!"/>
    <Label layoutX="206.0" layoutY="183.0" text="Press the button below to continue!"/>
</AnchorPane>
```

EDIT:
What stopped working: The application won't start, because fxmlloader puts out NPE.

I've tried changing the path to fxml file to a couple different formats:

```
"../resources/fxml/homepage.fxml"
"src/main/resources/fxml/homepage.fxml"
"../fxml/homepage.fxml"
"../homepage.fxml"
```

What I don't get is that with the very same code i have now it worked. Then i tried moving the fxml file to another package and it stopped working. I moved it back to the original place and it won't work either.

Comment: Forget everything starting with `..`. This ceases to work, if you build a `.jar` file. Where is the fxml relative to the classpath root at runtime/what's it's entry name in case you added it to a `.jar` file?

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699116/cant-load-fxml-in-another-package-javafx/53705531#53705531