# How do I write the path to a FXML file in my JavaFX application?

Tags: java, javafx, path, fxml

I'm trying to write the path in the main class to load a FXML file `MenuFXML.fxml` but I can't figure out the correct way to do so. The FXML file is in the package `com.developer.fxml` and the main class is in `com.developer`.

I've already tried the path `/com/developer/fxml/MenuFXML.fxml` and `/fxml/MenuFXML.fxml` but neither of them work.

```
package com.developer;

import com.developer.exit.ExitApplication;
import com.developer.util.css.AddCSS;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private final String title = "Stock Program 2.0";
    private Parent root;

    private final AddCSS addcss = new AddCSS();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setTitle(title);

        stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
            e.consume();
            ExitApplication ep = new ExitApplication();
            ep.closeProgram(stage);
        });

        //The part that I can't get to work
        root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/MenuFXML.fxml"));

        scene = new Scene(root);
        addcss.setStylesheet(scene);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the complete directory structure of your project. Tell us how you build it and run it.

Comment: @ThePower Remove the first slash. `root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/MenuFXML.fxml"));`

Comment: `/com/developer/fxml/MenuFXML.fxml` should work assuming there's no typo. If it does not work, you probably haven't included the resource in the classpath at runtime properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load FXML in another package (JavaFX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699116/cant-load-fxml-in-another-package-javafx)