# Create package in resources folder in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, javafx

I am working on a `JavaFX` project based on the [Henley Sales](https://github.com/p-smith/javafx-dataapp-sample) sample application and I would like to know if there is a way in `IntelliJ` to add a package structure in the `main/resources` folder, like it is allowed in the `main/java` folder ? In the sample project, they suggested to create your `FXML` files in the `main/resources` folder according to the package structure in the `main/java` folder.
Thanks.

Comment: As `IntelliJ` is the most intelligent Java IDE, creating the structure of the package by adding folders, displays it as a classic `package`. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the advice I've offered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699116/cant-load-fxml-in-another-package-javafx/53705531#53705531) related to loading FXML files as resources?

Comment: Very useful, thank you. I think it will be useful in `IntelliJ` if they add the option add `package` in the `resources` item when you right click.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click on the [resource content root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html), New | **Directory**, create a directory corresponding to the package, for `com.mycompany.myapp` package type `com/mycompany/myapp`. IDE will create the directory tree structure:

[image: resource]

Comment: which i found this 3 hours ago